# pagination not appearing in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

i have a table in php whose data comes from sql database, so i have kept a pagination for the table because the data is long

```html
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$perpage = 5;
if(isset($_GET['page']) & !empty($_GET['page'])){
 $curpage = $_GET['page'];
}else{
 $curpage = 1;
}
$start = ($curpage * $perpage) - $perpage;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `registers` LIMIT $start, $perpage";
$PageSql = "SELECT * FROM `registers`";
$pageres = mysqli_query($link, $PageSql);
$totalres = mysqli_num_rows($pageres);                             
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){                           
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
echo "<table class='table'>";    
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";

echo "<th class='serial'>ID</th>";
 echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "<th>Phone Number</th>";
echo "<th>Email</th>";
echo "<th>Action</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<a href='read.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
 // Free result set
 mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
 }
 } else{
 echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);

?>


<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
  <ul class="pagination">
  <?php if($curpage != $startpage){ ?>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php echo $startpage ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">First</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if($curpage >= 2){ ?>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php echo $previouspage ?>"><?php echo $previouspage ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php echo $curpage ?>"><?php echo $curpage ?></a></li>
    <?php if($curpage != $endpage){ ?>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php echo $nextpage ?>"><?php echo $nextpage ?></a></li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php echo $endpage ?>" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Last</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</nav>
<?php }?>
```

the data is correctly added into the database, but the problem is the pagination is nowhere seen in the page. when i just put the html it was coming,but when i added the php code inside it,its is not coming. can anyone tell me what could be the problem please?

Comment: Please format the code in your question properly. In it's current format, it's pretty hard to read and follow. There's also no point of posting PHP code as a JS snippet.

Comment: With "_pagination_" do you mean the formatting of the PHP file?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i tried to format the code properly but its not moving to left

Comment: @Teemu the data is coming from database, so i kept pagination so that i can limit data in one page and when the user clicks the pagination, rest of data will be in different pages

Comment: Just copy the code into some IDE or text editor, format it properly and then paste it back into your question. Your last edit actually made it worse.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson done.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the pagination is displayed when its written in html, but when i add php inside it to work, pagination is not even displayed

Comment: Please indent your code properly. When asking a question, it's important that you write it and format it properly. If it's hard for us to read the code, there's less chance that people stick around and help. At the end of the day, when asking people to help, the least you can do is to make sure the question is clear and easy to read. Before hitting the "save" button, take a step back, look at the preview of your question with objective eyes. If you wouldn't want to get the code in that format, then we probably don't want it like that either.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  whats wrong with the code now? i edited it .now its proper right?

Comment: You have a bunch of nested if-statements and echoes all with the same indention. From row 9 and down, all the PHP code has zero or 1-2 spaces as indention. It's hard to read and follow what that code does when.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson can you please check the code from <nav aria-label="Page navigation">, and see if anything is wrong, that is the prt which is not working

Comment: Sorry but not able to understand your question.

Comment: `if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){  } else { }` You show it only on else. .. Why you expect it to be visible?

Answer (score 0):

Move `<nav></nav>` code inside 
`if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ }`

Before or after your table.

Issue is that you now show it only if your `if` statement fails: `if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){ } else { }`

**Tip:**
To Prevent SQL Injection i suggest:
[PHP MySQLi Prepared Statements Tutorial](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection)

[PHP PDO Prepared Statements Tutorial](https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection)